# Rank over partition and group by column, how can I do it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-8.0

I have a database table containing player results/scores.
The data looks like this:

| player_id | result_date | score | game_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 154 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-03-15 | 171 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-03-15 | 122 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-03-17 | 210 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 190 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-05-15 | 125 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 167 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-06-10 | 173 | 1 |

I would like to get the top three players for each game type, and also be able to filter on date, but I'm not sure how to do that.

At the moment my query looks like this:

```
SELECT rr.* FROM 
(SELECT game_type, player_id, result_date, score,
RANK() OVER (partition by game_type ORDER BY score DESC) as game_rank
FROM results
WHERE result_date >= '2020-01-01') rr
HAVING game_rank <= 3;
```

But then the same player can be ranked multiple times.
I only want the best score from each player per game type. How can I do that?

The database is Mysql 8.0.

Comment: *But then the same player can be ranked multiple times. I only want the best score from each player per game type.* It is possible that some score for some player is not the best for this player but the best for the game... your algorithm does not allow to output this player. It is possible that some player is the best in 2 games - your algorithm does not allow to understand what game must this player to be returned with.

Comment: @Akina: It seems you are misunderstanding this part. As is, a player can be top 1 and 2 and 3 at the same time for a game type, but frofrik just wants them once (with their best score for the game type).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If so then the first step is simple `GROUP BY player,game` and get `MAX(score)`. Then rank and get top 3.

Comment: @Akina: Yep. `GROUP BY player_id, game_type` that is. And if you want the whole row, you use `PARTITION BY player_id, game_type` and `ROW_NUMBER` instead. This is what I am doing in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two steps:

1. Get the row with the best score per game type and player.
2. From that get the rows with the best score per game type.

The query:

```
select 
  game_type, player_id, result_date, score
from
(
  select
    game_type, player_id, result_date, score,
    dense_rank() over (partition by game_type order by score desc) as game_rank
  from 
  (
    select 
      game_type, player_id, result_date, score,
      row_number() over (partition by game_type, player_id order by score desc) as rn
    from results
    where result_date >= date '2020-01-01'
  ) top_games
  where rn = 1
) top_players
where game_rank <= 3
order by game_type, score desc;
```

In case a player scored top for one game type on more than one date, one is arbitrarily chosen by using `ROW_NUMBER`. As to players, we must also consider ties and decide whether to use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`. I'm using `DENSE_RANK` in my query.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the result I'm looking for.
The table contains 5M+ rows, so the query seems to be a bit slow if running over a longer date period. I do have an index with (result_date, game_type, score), but it doesn't seem to make any difference?

Comment: The index looks quite good, but as you want the players top score per game type, you should include the player: `create index idx on results (result_date, game_type, player_id, score desc)`. But well, it's up the the DBMS whether to use it or not. The longer the date period the less likely is the use of that index.

Comment: Okey, I can see that it's not using the index when I'm running a longer date period, and the query time is up to 20 seconds.. Is there anything I could change would you say?

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm not a MySQL guy. It does look like there is nothing we can do about it, but who knows? You may want to make this a new request including the execution plan. Maybe someone versed in MySQL can help then.